# Qt Application without full screen in iPad

Tags: ios, qt, ipad, qml, qt-creator

I am developing an application using Qt/QML and build the same for iPad.
I could successfully run on iPad.
My screen resolution is 500x500. But, in iPad it comes in fullscreen (1024x768) . How can I run the application in actual size in iPad.

Comment: Is that possible with Xcode? is it doable with Objective-C or Cocoa?

Comment: I could successfully resize the screen using Qt only. Thanks

Comment: Thats good, you could answer your question